# Is there a d-lang equivalent of Ruby's attr_accessor

Tags: d

In Ruby I can easily set read/write properties on a class like this:

```
class Bar
  attr_accessor :foo, :bizz, :buzz
end
```

This would be the same as

```
class Bar
  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def foo=(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def bizz
    @foo
  end

  def bizz=(bizz)
    @bizz = bizz
  end

  def buzz
    @buzz
  end

  def buzz=(buzz)
    @buzz = buzz
  end
end
```

The same code is D is very verbose, and I find myself repeating things all over the place:

```
class Bar {
  private {
    string _foo, _bizz, _buzz;
  }

  @property {
    string foo()  { return _foo;  }
    string bizz() { return _bizz; }
    string buzz() { return _buzz; }

    void foo(string foo)   { _foo = foo;   }
    void bizz(string bizz) { _bizz = bizz; }
    void buzz(string buzz) { _buzz = buzz; }
  }
}
```

Is there a short hand way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes:

```
public string foo;
```

Trivial property accessors are a waste of time IMO. Ruby forces you to do them but D doesn't.

If you want them anyway, a mixin template can do the job:

```
mixin template attr_accessor(Type, string name) {
    static string codeGenerationHelper() {
        string code;
        // the variable
        code ~= "private Type _" ~ name ~ ";";

        // the getter
        code ~= "public @property Type " ~ name ~ "() { return _" ~ name ~ "; }";

        // the setter
        code ~= "public @property Type " ~ name ~ "(Type a) { return _" ~ name ~ " = a; }";

        return code;
    }

    mixin(codeGenerationHelper());
}

// here's how to use it
class Foo {
    mixin attr_accessor!(string, "foo");
}

void main() {
    auto foo = new Foo();
    foo.foo = "test";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the `codeGenerationHelper()` bit to me some?

Comment: Yeah, what you do with these is build out the D code as a big string. Then, the mixin expression below tells the compiler to paste that code in here and compile it all. So here, we considered what the code would look like: a variable definition, a getter, then a setter function. So what we do in this helper function is just build that string. The `~` operator in D is string append/concat. We break up the string every so often to insert the name of the variable. Otherwise, the syntax probably looks harder than it is cuz of the quotes but it is just plain D code pasted together.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. The last thing I'm not understanding is how the `Type` variable works.  Also, what if I wanted to do something special, but only if `Type` is `string`?

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions... but can you combine these? Could you have a template that is `attr_reader` and one that is `attr_writer` and then just have `attr_accessor` call both of them?

Comment: Yes you could do attr_reader and attr_writer separately, though you'd need to be careful not to declare the variable twice. In my example, I declared the private variable in the generated code string. That should only be done once, so the two other attrs would need to handle that somehow

Comment: Type is an example of a template parameter. When we write attr_accessor!(string), string is passed as the argument, so inside that function every time we write `Type`, string is used instead.

Comment: Is there a way for me to use a `switch` statement with `Type`?

Comment: Actually, there might be, but typically you would use `static if(is(Type == some_type_name)) { /* do something here */ }` and then `else static if(other stuff ) ` and so on.

Comment: Okay cool. I *think* my last question =p What about a way to track some state like whether or not `attr_accessor` has been used yet on the `Foo` class? So the first time it's used it sets some variable to `true` and then subsequent calls to `attr_accessor` could check for that variable.

Comment: Yeah, it could use reflection to check for the presence of the variable in the class, but that's getting too complicated to explain in a comment...